# How to maintain equal perpendicular width between two bezier curve?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, math, svg

I am creating a link between points with bezier curve for Sankey chart.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
let 
  margin = 10,
  x0 = 20,
  y0 = 20,
  x1 = 150,
  y1 = 100,
  width = 30,
  path = d3.path(),
  path2 = d3.path(),
  controlPointX = (x0 + x1) / 2;

/* with filled path */
path.moveTo(x0, y0);
path.bezierCurveTo(controlPointX, y0, controlPointX, y1, x1, y1);
path.lineTo(x1, y1 + width);
path.bezierCurveTo(controlPointX, y1 + width, controlPointX, y0 + width, x0, y0 + width);
path.closePath();

let svg = d3.select('svg');
let g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);
g.append('path')
  .attr('d', path)
  .attr('fill', 'red');

// curve 2 offset
y0 += 120;
y1 += 120;

// with stroke
path2.moveTo(x0, y0);
path2.bezierCurveTo(controlPointX, y0, controlPointX, y1, x1, y1);
g.append('path')
  .attr('d', path2)
  .attr('stroke-width', width)
  .attr('stroke', 'blue')
  .attr('fill', 'none');
```

[image]

In the first approach, the perpendicular width between two curve is not same. But in the second example, I have used the same single curve and stroke-with for height and that works perfectly. I want to achieve the same with filled path.

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/3cxt40Lz/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to offset a cubic bezier curve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148831/how-to-offset-a-cubic-bezier-curve)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an *approximate* solution.

I opened the generated SVG in a vector editing software, in order to check the Bezier curve's control points.

[image]

Playing around a little, it turned out that shifting the lower control points horizontally to the left hand side adapted the curve as desired:

[image]

So back to the code, created a new control point shifted to the left by `width / 2`:

```
controlPointX2 = (x0 + x1 - width) / 2;

/* with filled path */
path.moveTo(x0, y0);
path.bezierCurveTo(controlPointX, y0, controlPointX, y1, x1, y1);
path.lineTo(x1, y1 + width);
path.bezierCurveTo(controlPointX2, y1 + width, controlPointX2, y0 + width, x0, y0 + width);
```

The result is not exactly as the blue curve, but very close, as illustrated below where the red curve is shown above the blue one (with some transparency).

[image: result]

Updated jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zbe90rjq/1/